# Problems installing / using CleverHans library

Tags: python, tensorflow, cleverhans

I try to install or use the cleverhans library with tensorflow but it fails. (Cleverhans 3.0.1)

I tried TF 1.12, 1.13, 1.15, 2.0, 2.3.1 but everytime another error occured when using the tutorial code.

For example:
TF 2.3.1 --> *module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GraphKeys'*
TF 1.13.1 --> some tf.keras.v1 api calls do not work

Is there any working configuration for using cleverhans with tensorflow? Should I use an older version of cleverhans?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found any solution?